# Count records in table and show line number of specific value

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm looking to find the position of a value within a result set AND the total number of results in that set.

In the example below, ID-101 is part of a set of 3 records, and is located at position #2 within that set.

**tblData**

```
ID     Type  Order   
100    P     1       
101    P     2       
102    P     3
```

**Result**

```
cntRec    intPos
3         2
```

Example #2
In the example below, ID-101 is part of a set of 3 records, the ordering is changed (by the user) and is located at position #1 within that set.

**tblData**

```
ID     Type  Order   
100    P     3       
101    P     1       
102    P     2
```

**Result**

```
cntRec    intPos
3         1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the query with the window function:

```
DECLARE @intPos AS INT = 0;

;WITH RowCountCte AS (
   SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS intPos
   FROM tblData
)

SELECT @intPos = intPos FROM RowCountCte WHERE ID = 101;

SELECT COUNT(ID) AS cntRec, @intPos AS intPos
FROM tblData;
```

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a2a1e5375fc61f467bede8d14d6577f6)

Comment: Thanks - in your example, intPos should be '2', not '3' - due to order column ?

Comment: @BigIWT So `intPos` is not the position of the `101` in the table? Is it simply the `101`'s `Order` column value?

Comment: As per you comment, are you expecting this [query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=87b7c988a5658d7396db6a1893314792) ?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select count(*) as cntrec,
       sum(case when id <= 101 then 1 else 0 end) as intpos
from t;
```

Comment: thanks - yes, but my bad as I forgot to mention the 'ordering' field - original question updated.